# R dtplyr using mutated columns in functions

Tags: r, dtplyr

I have data in lazy_tbl and create columns which I would to use in future to calculate something else, but I'm missing something as getting errors. Here is example.

```
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(implied)

#helper
possibly_mean <- possibly(mean, otherwise = NA)

ready_to_calculate %>% 
  lazy_dt() %>% 
  mutate(avgH = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$home_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgD = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$draw_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgA = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$away_odds, na.rm = T)),
         prob1 = pmap_dbl(list(avgH, avgD, avgA), ~implied::implied_probabilities(c(..1, ..2, ..3), method = "wpo")$probabilities[1,1]))
```

This will give me following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(copy(`_DT20`), , `:=`(c("avgH", "avgD", "avgA",  : 
  Variable '1' is not found in calling scope. Looking in calling scope because this symbol was prefixed with .. in the j= parameter.
```

If I use `as_tibble()` before mutating last row, I will get answer I'm looking for. So what am I missing here and how can I use just created columns in formulas in future?

```
ready_to_calculate %>% 
  lazy_dt() %>% 
  mutate(avgH = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$home_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgD = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$draw_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgA = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$away_odds, na.rm = T))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(prob1 = pmap_dbl(list(avgH, avgD, avgA), ~implied::implied_probabilities(c(..1, ..2, ..3), method = "wpo")$probabilities[1,1]))

# A tibble: 2 × 7
  home_team away_team   odds_1x2       avgH  avgD  avgA  prob1
  <chr>     <chr>       <list>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Arsenal   Aston Villa <df [18 × 4]>  1.96  3.64  3.92  0.496
2 Leeds     Wolves      <lgl [1]>     NA    NA    NA    NA
```

DATA:

```
dput(ready_to_calculate)
structure(list(home_team = c("Arsenal", "Leeds"), away_team = c("Aston Villa", 
"Wolves"), odds_1x2 = list(structure(list(bookmaker = c("10Bet", 
"188BET", "1xBet", "888sport", "bet-at-home", "bet365", "Betfair", 
"Betsafe", "Betsson", "BetVictor", "Betway", "bwin", "ComeOn", 
"Interwetten", "Pinnacle", "Unibet", "William Hill", "Betfair Exchange"
), home_odds = c(2.05, 2.02, 1.84, 1.93, 2.02, 1.85, 1.91, 2.05, 
2.05, 1.95, 1.91, 1.9, 2.05, 1.95, 2.04, 1.96, 1.91, 1.97), draw_odds = c(3.6, 
3.6, 3.85, 3.6, 3.6, 3.75, 3.7, 3.65, 3.65, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.65, 
3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.6, 3.61), away_odds = c(3.65, 3.8, 4.41, 4.1, 
3.65, 4, 4.2, 3.7, 3.7, 4, 4, 4, 3.75, 3.85, 3.87, 4.1, 3.9, 
3.95)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 18L)), NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the anonymous lambda function combined with accessing the elements with `..1` etc. is the problem. We can put this in a custom function and just call it as bare function name inside `pmap_dbl`:

```r
library(dtplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(implied)

#helper
possibly_mean <- possibly(mean, otherwise = NA)

calc_implied_probalities <- function(x,y,z) {
  out <- implied_probabilities(
    c(x, y, z),
    method = "wpo")$probabilities[1,1]
}

ready_to_calculate %>% 
  lazy_dt() %>% 
  mutate(avgH = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$home_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgD = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$draw_odds, na.rm = T)),
         avgA = map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$away_odds, na.rm = T)),
         prob1 = pmap_dbl(list(avgH, avgD, avgA), calc_implied_probalities)
         )

#> Source: local data table [2 x 7]
#> Call:   copy(`_DT1`)[, `:=`(c("avgH", "avgD", "avgA", "prob1"), {
#>     avgH <- map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$home_odds, na.rm = TRUE))
#>     avgD <- map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$draw_odds, na.rm = TRUE))
#>     avgA <- map_dbl(odds_1x2, ~possibly_mean(.x$away_odds, na.rm = TRUE))
#>     prob1 <- pmap_dbl(list(avgH, avgD, avgA), ..calc_implied_probalities)
#>     .(avgH, avgD, avgA, prob1)
#> })]
#> 
#>   home_team away_team   odds_1x2       avgH  avgD  avgA  prob1
#>   <chr>     <chr>       <list>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Arsenal   Aston Villa <df [18 × 4]>  1.96  3.64  3.92  0.496
#> 2 Leeds     Wolves      <lgl [1]>     NA    NA    NA    NA    
#> 
#> # Use as.data.table()/as.data.frame()/as_tibble() to access results
```

Data from OP:

```r
ready_to_calculate <- structure(list(home_team = c("Arsenal", "Leeds"), away_team = c("Aston Villa", 
                                                                                      "Wolves"), odds_1x2 = list(structure(list(bookmaker = c("10Bet", 
                                                                                                                                              "188BET", "1xBet", "888sport", "bet-at-home", "bet365", "Betfair", 
                                                                                                                                              "Betsafe", "Betsson", "BetVictor", "Betway", "bwin", "ComeOn", 
                                                                                                                                              "Interwetten", "Pinnacle", "Unibet", "William Hill", "Betfair Exchange"
                                                                                      ), home_odds = c(2.05, 2.02, 1.84, 1.93, 2.02, 1.85, 1.91, 2.05, 
                                                                                                       2.05, 1.95, 1.91, 1.9, 2.05, 1.95, 2.04, 1.96, 1.91, 1.97), draw_odds = c(3.6, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 3.6, 3.85, 3.6, 3.6, 3.75, 3.7, 3.65, 3.65, 3.6, 3.6, 3.5, 3.65, 
                                                                                                                                                                                 3.6, 3.65, 3.7, 3.6, 3.61), away_odds = c(3.65, 3.8, 4.41, 4.1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3.65, 4, 4.2, 3.7, 3.7, 4, 4, 4, 3.75, 3.85, 3.87, 4.1, 3.9, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                           3.95)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 18L)), NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -2L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think if you add that lazy_dt, before rowwise() it stops working. I got this kind of error. Error in UseMethod("rowwise") : 
  no applicable method for 'rowwise' applied to an object of class "c('dtplyr_step_first', 'dtplyr_step')". I want to use lazy_dt as calculations are faster when you have a lot of data.

Comment: @Hakki: Sorry, I apparently thought `ready_to_calculate` was a `lazy_dt`. I now updated the answer and reverted to using `purrr::pmap()` with a custom function.